# Aysnc Task --My App's Memory Consumption is Getting Higer Slowly ,Why?

Tags: c#

I use 'Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll()' to improve app's performance,but i got a problem that the memory is slowly getting higher.

Then i use the GC.collect() and GC.GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers() and i got the same situation.

```
      int taskCount = Settings.Default.TaskCount;
        int monitorInterval = Settings.Default.MonitorInterval;
        while (true)
        {


            using (TaskHandleSvr taskItem = new TaskHandleSvr())
            {
                List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();
                for (int i = 0; i < taskCount; i++)
                    taskList.Add(taskItem.RegisterRun());
                await Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(taskList.ToArray(), wordCountTasks =>
                {
                    int count = taskItem.ProcessMisseHandledRedisMsg();

                    string sLogTime = $"{DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(8).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ffff")}";
                    string sLogName = "-";
                    string sLogMessage = "Service End！";
                    NLogHelper.Info($"{sLogName}*|*{sLogTime}*|*Loop{count}Msg");
                    NLogHelper.Info($"{sLogName}*|*{sLogTime}*|*{sLogMessage}");
                });
                taskItem.Dispose();
                GC.Collect();
                GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            }
            //Console.ReadKey();
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
        }
```

//Below is the TaskHandleSvr

Comment: `Then i use the GC.collect() and GC.GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers() and i got the same situation` what does this mean exactly, also use a memory profiler if you think you have a memory leak

Comment: On average how big can the `taskcount` get?

Comment: Are you sure you dispose everything in `taskItem.Dispose();`?

Comment: taskitem seems to be growing and not getting disponsed

Comment: Task Manager is not an appropriate memory profiler, it uses the wrong statistic.  Five seconds is simply far too long to have a shot at seeing the saw-tooth pattern that is typical of GC memory usage.  Remove Task.Delay(), remove GC.Collect(), use Perfmon.exe to look at the .NET memory counters, let it run  over the weekend.  Then use a memory profiler.

Answer (score 1):

Here i am ! Finally, i got my bug fixed. Whoa~

1. use 'static' task
2. there is a wrong place at "taskList.Add(taskItem.RegisterRun())", it should be 'taskList.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(fn =>{TaskHandleSvr.RegisterRun().Wait(); }, null))'.  After i printed threadid in 'RegisterRun()', i found that the current thread managed id is the same number. Then i realized there is something wrong with using multiple thread.
3. In case of not realsing memory in tasks, i use 'Task.Dispose()'

Thanks the Comments Upstairs, sincerely thank U~

Below is the Code

```
protected override async Task RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{

    int taskCount= Settings.Default.TaskCount;
    int monitorIntervalSeconds = Settings.Default.MonitorInterval;
    List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();
     while (true)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < taskCount; i++)
            taskList.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(fn => { TaskHandleSvr.RegisterRun().Wait(); }, null));
        await Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(taskList.ToArray(), wordCountTasks =>
         {
                int count = TaskHandleSvr.ProcessMisseHandledRedisMsg().Result;                   
                string sLogTime = $"{DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(8).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ffff")}";
                string sLogName = "--myTaskGroup--";
                string sLogMessage = "Task End";
                NLogHelper.Info($"{sLogName}*|*{sLogTime}*|*RollBack {count} Message");
                NLogHelper.Info($"{sLogName}*|*{sLogTime}*|*{sLogMessage}");
        });

         //Release Resource
        foreach (var item in taskList)
            item.Dispose();
        taskList.RemoveRange(0, taskList.Count);

        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(monitorIntervalSeconds), cancellationToken);
    }
}
```